# Regex: extract last occurence of pattern

Tags: regex, scala

I have an address string and I need to extract the street name from it. Examples:

```
Unit 1, Silicon Way -> Silicon Way
66 Yellow Brick Road -> Yellow  Brick Road
77 - 5 Sesame Street -> Sesame Street
High Street -> High Street
```

How would a regular expression look like in this case? If language matters I'm using Scala.

Comment: What is the pattern, is it always after a number or what?

Comment: @sshashank124 Yes, but there could be a comma after a number like in the first example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This regex will not work if address contains comma or number in it.** If the address is always the text from the end of the string, then try with this regex:

```
\s*([a-zA-Z ]+?)\s*$
```

`$` is anchoring as end of string. So the pattern will always match from the right side of the string.

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR5zT3)